# Unable to make my script wait conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've tried to write a script in python in combination with selenium to wait for a certain element to be available. The content I wish my script waits for is captcha protected. I do not want to set a fixed time. So, I need it to wait until I can solve myself.

I've tried like:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

URL = "https://www.someurl.com/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
while not driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".listing-content"):
    time.sleep(1)

print(driver.current_url)
driver.quit()
```

But, the script throws an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

***How can I make my script wait until the element is available no matter how long it takes?***

Comment: Have you tried running the find_elment_by_css_selector function inside a try/except block inside your while-loop?

Comment: can you loop while captcha present?

Comment: Yes, I tried that way @QHarr. The script throws an error as soon as I solve that captcha because that while loop no longer exists and this line `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".listing-content")` throws the same error (cosider that the selector contains captcha element).

Comment: Same within a try block?

Comment: I can't organize that try/except block in the right way. How can try/except block run indefinitely?

Comment: @robots.txt What kind of captcha are you dealing with? Simple text captcha?

Comment: Nope, they are of vicious type like google @DebanjanB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to hardcode wait time you can use ExplicitWait along with `float("inf")` which in Python stands for *INFINITY*:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait(driver, float("inf")).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "listing-content")))
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've asked how to organize the try/except block, here is an idea. I would suggest to stick with the inf-wait method however.

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".listing-content")
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

I would include the time.sleep() statement to minimize your number of function calls.

Comment: `if ret:` is redundant here: `break` will be executed ONLY if `ret = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".listing-content")` doesn't raise an exception

Answer (score 1):

You should use WebDriverWait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".listing-content")))
```

It will not wait indefinitely, but you can set the timeout high. Otherwise you could try to use the WebDriverWait statement in a loop.